# Program was not found .dll file

Tags: c++, opencv

I try to follow https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d18/tutorial_sfm_scene_reconstruction.html this code but it can't build. I use opencv and extra-contrib version 3.4.5

I tried to add .dll to project but it not work.

````
'scenceRecon.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'scenceRecon.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'scenceRecon.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'scenceRecon.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\opencv\laster\install\x86\vc15\bin\opencv_core345d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'scenceRecon.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\opencv\laster\install\x86\vc15\bin\opencv_sfm345d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'scenceRecon.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\opencv\laster\install\x86\vc15\bin\opencv_viz345d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'scenceRecon.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp140d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'scenceRecon.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vcruntime140d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'scenceRecon.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbased.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'scenceRecon.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\concrt140d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'scenceRecon.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\opencv\laster\install\x86\vc15\bin\opencv_xfeatures2d345d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'scenceRecon.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\opencv\laster\install\x86\vc15\bin\opencv_features2d345d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'scenceRecon.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\opencv\laster\install\x86\vc15\bin\opencv_flann345d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'scenceRecon.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\opencv\laster\install\x86\vc15\bin\opencv_imgcodecs345d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'scenceRecon.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'scenceRecon.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\win32u.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'scenceRecon.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'scenceRecon.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32full.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'scenceRecon.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp_win.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'scenceRecon.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
The thread 0x27dc has exited with code -1073741515 (0xc0000135).
The thread 0x1f78 has exited with code -1073741515 (0xc0000135).
The program '[6608] scenceRecon.exe' has exited with code -1073741515 (0xc0000135) 'A dependent dll was not found'.```
````

and this .exe error

[image]

Comment: I believe the solution is to figure out where that missing dll is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common pattern for Windows API frameworks. You install/build some framework which comes with a set of INCLUDE, LIB, and DLL files.  Your code includes the headers and links with the DLL's stub lib file in order to compile.  But at runtime, the dependent DLLs can't be found, because they aren't in your PATH (or in the same folder as an EXE).

The dialog is literally telling you the error.  Copy ceres-debug.dll into the same folder as the EXE.  Or preferably, as explained above, just make sure that whatever folder containing ceres-debug.dll is in your PATH environment variable. By updating the PATH, you likely resolve many subsequent errors for the additional DLL your program or ceres-debug.dll depend on.

Make sense?

Also, a quick google for "DLL Search Order" has several good articles that explain this topic: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order