# How do I define the curl library with cmake at vscode?

Tags: c++, curl, cmake

I am compiling without errors.But the program doesn't work.I think program isn't seeing curl lib.

When I try to debug the program, I catch this error ("ERROR: Unable to start debugging. Unexpected GDB output from command "-exec-run". During startup program exited with code 0xc0000135.")

Working Environment Information:

```
    Os:W7 64bit 
    Vs Code 1.44.1
    gcc version 9.3.0  
    curl w7 64 bit //https://curl.haxx.se/windows/dl-7.69.1_1/curl-7.69.1_1-win64-mingw.zip
    gdb (GDB) 9.1    
    CMake 3.17
```

Project Folder:

```
 |   CMakeLists.txt
    |   
    +---.vscode
    |       .easycpp
    |       c_cpp_properties.json
    |       launch.json
    |       settings.json
    |       tasks.json
    |       
    +---bin             
    +---include
    |   \---curl
    |           curl.h
    |           curlver.h
    |           easy.h
    |           mprintf.h
    |           multi.h
    |           stdcheaders.h
    |           system.h
    |           typecheck-gcc.h
    |           urlapi.h
    |           
    +---lib
    |       libcurl.a
    |       libcurl.dll.a
    |       
    \---src
            main.cpp
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(main VERSION 0.1.0)

include(CTest)
enable_testing()

file(GLOB TARGET_SRC "./src/*.cpp" )

add_definitions( -DCURL_STATICLIB )

set( CURL_LIBRARY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib )
set( CURL_INCLUDE_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include )
find_package( CURL )

include_directories( ${CURL_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
link_directories( ${CURL_LIBRARIES} )

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${TARGET_SRC})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} curl)


set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "curl/curl.h"

int main(void)
{
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl)
    {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://postit.example.com/moo.cgi");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "name=daniel&project=curl");

        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        if (res != CURLE_OK)
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
                    curl_easy_strerror(res));

        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }

    curl_global_cleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

**I don't know where the error is. The problem may be caused by the curl library. I can try to use with compile curl source, but Visual Studio is not installed.How can I solve the problem?**

Comment: The error `0xc0000135` means one ore more dependent DLLs cannot be found. Add the directories where the DLLs reside to your path, e.g. `set PATH=C:\Curl\bin;%PATH%`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Program was not found .dll file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55437129/program-was-not-found-dll-file)